# Algorithm for quickly obtaining a partial ordering over multiple linked lists

Tags: algorithm, list, linked-list

I have a situation, as follows:

- I have *n* doubly-linked lists
- Each list has a sentinel beginning and end
- The lists all have the **same** beginning and end node (not required, but for simplicity's sake)
- The lists are homogenous and may share items

I'd like to find a partial ordering of all nodes in all *n* lists, starting with the beginning node and ending with, well, the end node, such that any node which appears in *n-x* lists, where *x < n*, will be sorted with respect to the other nodes in all the lists in which it appears.

Using arrays to provide an example set of lists:

```
first  = [a, b,    d,    f,    h, i];
second = [a, b, c,       f, g,    i];
third  = [a,          e, f, g, h, i];
```

Obviously, one possible answer would be [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], but another admissible ordering would be [a, b, d, e, c, f, g, h, i].

I know that there **is** a fast algorithm to do this, does anybody remember how it goes or what it is called? I already have a few slow versions, but I'm certain that somewhere in Knuth there is a far faster one.

(And, before you ask, this is not for homework or Project Euler, and I cannot make this any more concrete. This *is* the problem.)

Edit: I am relatively sure that the partial ordering is defined only as long as the endpoints are in all of the lists and in the same positions (beginning and end). I would not be against a linear-time search to find those endpoints, and if they can't be found, then an error could be raised there.

Comment: What would the answer(s) be if the lists had conflicting orders, e.g. `first = [a, b]` and `second = [b, a]`?

Comment: antinome: As mentioned in the above edit, I'd rather raise an error ahead of time if there's no way to get valid endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks very similar to [Topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) to me. There's several algorithms to get you a topologically sorted state. The one I particularly like is similar to a breadth first search. Maintain two lists, one of all nodes which have no in-edges, say `L` (initially just the `a` node), the other with the partial ordered nodes, `F`. Now at every step,

```
pick a node from `L`, 
do some operations (explained later), 
and move the chosen node to the `F` list.
```

In the "do some operations step",

```
choose all successors of the source node which have exactly one in-link add them to L.
Remove the link from the source node to all the successors in the previous step
```

Now, the list `F` has all your nodes topologically sorted. I'm sorry about the awful explanation, the wiki link has nice diagrams :)

Comment: There's even a section about the relation to partial orders. I like this idea quite a lot, and can see the elegance in it. The problem, then, would be an efficient transformation from the multiple linked lists (which are not multiply-linked!) to a DAG. Ideas?

Comment: So the object `a` in the first list isn't the same object `a` in the second list? I don't follow. If thats the case, use a hashtable (or any similar structure) to map each object to a common number. Then build the DAG. For instance `a` = 1, `b` = 2 etc etc. Now, build your DAG using the 1s and 2s instead of `a`s and `b`s

Comment: @MostAwesomeDude: I don't understand your question: anything applicable to a DAG must surely be applicable to something that is more than a DAG(more in the sense that edges go both ways). If you're stuck on how to convert your lists to a graph, you've made an ideal assumption for that problem: all first nodes in each list are equal. Therefore that is the ideal root of your graph, and each list represents a branch

Comment: I was just confused on the complexity of the transformation, but I can see how Kahn's algorithm could work on the linked lists directly, and so I could go with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Either I'm misunderstanding, or alienhard's algorithm can fail.  (I would add this as a comment, but I'm too new here to comment.)

Consider this example:

```
first  = [a, b, c, d,             i];
second = [a,       d, e, f,       i];
third  = [a,             f, g, h, i];
```

Alienhard's algorithm will give: `a=0, b=1, c=2, d=3, e=2, f=3, g=2, h=3, i=4`.

The algorithm then requires that e preceed d even though e follows d in second.

Comment: Yea, thanks, you are right. I also just figured that there are trivial cases where this fails. Would have been too nice if it worked that simple and fast ;). I've flagged my answer for deletion.